# Copy and Pasting excel data from unopened excel sheet to destination excel sheet to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste data from one excel sheet to another sheet into the last available row. My current code is overwriting the previous data. I would like to add data to last available row. Please help.

Sub CopyToExcel()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

```
WB_1 = ThisWorkbook.Name
WB_2 = "Analysis.xls"
b_file = "C:\\" & WB_2

On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open (b_file)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Cannot find " & WB_2 & "-file!")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

t_max = Workbooks(WB_2).Sheets("Page 1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks(WB_2).Sheets("Page 1").Range("A1:R" & 100).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(WB_1).Sheets("DB2").Range("C1")
Workbooks(WB_2).Close SaveChanges:=False
Workbooks(WB_1).Activate

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

End Sub

Comment: I dont see you finding the last row in `WB_1` nor can I see you using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you finding the last row in `WB_1` nor can I see you using that?. My suggestion: Work with objects. It becomes easier to understand what you are doing and you have a better control over the code.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim lRowDest As Long, lRowSource As Long

    '~~> This is the workbook where you want to copy
    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> This is the worksheet where you want to copy
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("DB2")
    '~~> This is the last row where the data will be copied
    lRowDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> This is the workbook FROM where you want to copy
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Analysis.xls")
    '~~> This is the worksheet FROM where you want to copy
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Page 1")

    With wsSource
        '~~> This is the last row till where the data will be copied from
        lRowSource = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Do the final Copy
        .Range("A1:R" & lRowSource).Copy wsDest.Range("C" & lRowDest)
    End With

    wbSource.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth Rout. It has fulfilled my requirement.